# Генерация рандомного 15-значного ключа

Tags: php

Нужно сделать генерацию ключа (который будет использоваться как инвайты для регистрации) из 15 латинских букв так, чтоб они не повторялись. То-есть при нажатии на кнопку у пользователя должно генерироваться по 10 новых ключей.

Проблема в том, что при обычной генерации ключи могут повторяться. И как тогда сгенерировать ключ? Также нужно чтоб ключи отличались друг от друга. Чтоб их нельзя было подобрать. (Например все буквы сначала одинаковые, и только последняя отличается). Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string

Comment: *чтоб они не повторялись* Буквы в ключе, ключи в пакете из 10 штук, или ключи вообще за всё время?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID

Comment: А что мешает воспользоваться GUID'ми?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону как уже написали GUID идентификатора

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте базу данных ключей, чтобы избежать повторений. 
Алгоритм:
1. Cоздаете ключ.
2. Проверяете есть ли такой в базе.
  2.1. В случае если такой ключ есть, повторяете пункт 1
  2.2. Если нету ключа, добавляете в базу

======

Сама генерация ключа может быть следующая:

```
function get_key(){
   return substr(uniqid(rand()), 0, 15);
}
```